# How to match each line of a text file contents in powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a text file 'abc.txt' that contains the below.
hello_1
hello_2
..
..
hello_n

I need to write a script to open the file abc.txt and read each line and store that each line in a variable called $temp. I need to read the line only that starts with 'hello'.  What is wrong with the below code?
I have the below Code:

```
foreach ($line in Get-Content "c:\folder\abc.txt")    
{    
    if($line Select-String -Pattern 'hello')
    $temp=$line
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
$temp = @()
(Get-Content "c:\folder\abc.txt") | % {$temp += $_ | Select-String -Pattern "hello"}
$temp
```

The code is getting the content of `abc.txt`, and for each object checking if the pattern matches `hello`. If it's a match, then it stores the corresponding value in the array defined as `$temp`.

**OR**

You can rephrase your original code like this -

```
$temp = @()
foreach ($line in Get-Content "c:\folder\abc.txt")    
{    
    if($line | Select-String -Pattern 'hello') {
    $temp += line
    }
}
```

In you original code, you are missing a [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-6) in the statement `if($line Select-String -Pattern 'hello')`. And you are missing [braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245858/powershell-missing-statement-block-after-if)`{}` to enclose the if statement.

Comment: This worked perfectly fine. Can you let me know what is wrong with my original code in for statement? or what change i needed in the for statement code? i'm just curious to know being a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You missing pipeline after `$line`, and curly braces are missing in the whole scriptblock `{` and `}` after the `foreach`, should be:

```
foreach ($line in Get-Content "c:\folder\abc.txt")    
{    
    {
    if($line | Select-String -Pattern 'hello')
    $temp=$line
    }
}
```

Also, I don't know what is your purpose, but if you want `$line` will not be overwrited each time you should create an array outside of the iterration and fill it each time:

so first is: `$line = @()` and instead of `$temp=$line` change to `$temp += $line`

But then again if all your purpose is to filter the `hello` string from the text file then this should be enough:

```
$temp = (Get-Content "c:\folder\abc.txt") -match '^hello'
```

Comment: Im getting the error as "Missing statement block after if ( condition )."

Comment: That's because you are missing the `braces({})` after the if statement.